# List Columns not available as an option for crawled property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, crawled-property

We are operating on SharePoint 365 and I am trying to configure a custom search query.  To this effect, I'd like to map a managed property (i.e. refinablestring05) to a column in a list.  However, when editing the properties for a managed property, the column I'd like to reference is not showing up.  In fact, none of the list columns are showing up.

I have reindexed the list, the site (which is a sub site) and the parent site.  I have ensured that SharePoint Server functions are active (both at the parent site and sub site).  I have also confirmed that the list and the site are set to searchable and available.

I have also confirmed that the columns in the list contain data.  I have waited 15, 30min, 1 hour and even 24 hours for the site to be reindexed and crawled, but still these columns are not appearing.

What am I missing?  Hopefully this is enough information to suggest some points to troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Comment: So it has been more than enough time for the system to locate my columns but they are still not showing.  I even added a new site column and it too isn't showing up.  Any suggestions on why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it appears my issues might be due to SP148979 - Issues with search schema settings.  According to MS a fix should be coming out October 19th.  Will try my implementation at that time and hope that corrects my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Columns, depending on how they are created are not inherently searchable. If the person creating them just used the "+" sign to add them, that would be your problem. Columns should be created by clicking on the Ribbon under Library or List, then clicking create column. I would recommend creating a sample column this way, inputting some test data, and then running your search against the new column.

I unfortunately do not know of an easy way to move the data input into all the bad columns into new good columns. Nor do I know of a way to make the bad columns good. But at least the root issue should be known. While tedious, if you use the edit items functionality you should be able to at least copy paste from the data in the bad columns' cells into the good columns' cells.

Good luck!

More info here:
[Info from ShareGate](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/understand-sharepoint-crawled-and-managed-properties-for-search)

Comment: All the columns were added through the list settings.  All columns, and rows, contain data (I even went in and put NA in any blank fields).

Answer (score 0):

Is your field a Site Column? Because a custom field must be a Site Column to use it as a Crawled property. You can see a good example [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/o365totd/2015/12/11/using-site-columns-to-create-searchable-metadata-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/)

Comment: I do not believe this is the case.  I am trying to duplicate some functionality from another area of our site.  In that scenario the columns being mapped to a refinablestring are not a site column, they are only a list column.  I did notice in that other case that the referenced list was at the parent root site, so I will attempt to see if that is the difference, although it feels like that shouldn't matter.